cannot install pyqt5-tools since qmake is not recognised in PATH although I've added it?
currently I'm trying to install pyqt5-tools from gitbash/cmd etc, but for some odd reason it just will not recognise the qmake.exe file even though I've set it up in PATH or system variables.
Now what is strange is that if I name a direct path to the qmake.exe file to check its version it can read it, so the file itself seems to be downloaded correctly.
I've attempted redownloading the QT repositories and as well checking and installing the latest python sip version.
I'm incredibly new to the field of python programming so beside from what people have suggested online that are having the same issues (on stackoverlow and github) I'm pretty clueless on if I'm missing something massive like a certain version or installation that I should be aware of?
Here is the following code for what happens whenever I run the command:
$ pip install pyqt5-tools
Collecting pyqt5-tools
  Using cached pyqt5_tools-5.15.9.3.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.3 kB)
Collecting click (from pyqt5-tools)
  Using cached click-8.1.7-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.0 kB)
Collecting pyqt5==5.15.9 (from pyqt5-tools)
  Using cached PyQt5-5.15.9-cp37-abi3-win_amd64.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of pyqt5-tools to determine which vers
ion is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting pyqt5-tools
  Using cached pyqt5_tools-5.15.4.3.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.3 kB)
Collecting pyqt5==5.15.4 (from pyqt5-tools)
  Using cached PyQt5-5.15.4.tar.gz (3.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [32 lines of output]
      pyproject.toml: line 7: using '[tool.sip.metadata]' to specify the project
 metadata is deprecated and will be removed in SIP v7.0.0, use '[project]' inste
ad
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\"my name"\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-pa
ckages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <mo
dule>
          main()
          ~~~~^^
        File "C:\Users\"my name"\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-pa
ckages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in mai
n
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\"my name"\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-pa
ckages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 152, in pre
pare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings
)
        File "C:\Users\"my name"\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_qo25tyu\overlay\L
ib\site-packages\sipbuild\api.py", line 28, in build_wheel
          project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('wheel',
                  arguments=_convert_config_settings(config_settings))
        File "C:\Users\"my name"\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_qo25tyu\overlay\L
ib\site-packages\sipbuild\abstract_project.py", line 74, in bootstrap
          project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\"my name"\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_qo25tyu\overlay\L
ib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 608, in setup
          self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\"my name"\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-oj5i8y8r\pyqt5_4da19
a971f1d4f8493c6c8398f55489c\project.py", line 63, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\"my name"\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_qo25tyu\overlay\L
ib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\project.py", line 51, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\"my name"\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_qo25tyu\overlay\L
ib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 237, in apply_user_defaults
          self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\"my name"\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_qo25tyu\overlay\L
ib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\builder.py", line 50, in apply_user_defaults
          raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
                  "specify a working qmake or add it to PATH")
      sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem wit
h pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.


Try his py -m pip install PyQt5Designer

Just checked and yep this is already satisfied ...
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5Designer in c:\users"my name"\appdata\local\pro
grams\python\python313\lib\site-packages (5.14.1)

Did u upgrade PyQt6? py -m pip install PyQt6 Released: Jul 19, 2024
